# Converting numbers to words in ruby - improving my recursion solution

Tags: ruby, string, recursion

The problem has you convert numbers into words - 300 would translate to "three hundred". I know this question has been addressed on stack overflow, but I am seeking some advice regarding my specific recursion solution.

My solution works for all numbers except numbers like: 
100, 1000, 1000000

The above will return as "hundred", "thousand", "million". I understand why this happens.

300, 3300, 32000, 35000, etc. Any number % 100 or 1000 or 1000000 == 0 will return as "three thousand three hundred zero" .

My only successful idea was to use a second method `get_words` to delete "zero" from the solution after running the number through `in_words` if number was greater than 0, and just return "one" + number rather then run it through `in_words` if the number is 100/1000/1000000...

Its possible that my solution can only work like this due to the limitations of using recursion here, but maybe i'm missing something. Can anyone offer a way to tweak my solution to fix this problem?

```
NUMBER_DICTIONARY = {
  0 => "zero",
  1 => "one",
  2 => "two",
  3 => "three",
  4 => "four",
  5 => "five",
  6 => "six",
  7 => "seven",
  8 => "eight",
  9 => "nine",
  10 => "ten",
  11 => "eleven",
  12 => "twelve",
  13 => "thirteen",
  14 => "fourteen",
  15 => "fifteen",
  16 => "sixteen",
  17 => "seventeen",
  18 => "eighteen",
  19 => "nineteen",
  20 => "twenty",
  30 => "thirty",
  40 => "forty",
  50 => "fifty",
  60 => "sixty",
  70 => "seventy",
  80 => "eighty",
  90 => "ninety",
  100 => "hundred",
  1000 => "thousand",
  1000000 => "million"
  }

def get_words(number)
  result = in_words(number)
  return  "one" + " " + NUMBER_DICTIONARY[number] if (number == 100 || number == 1000 || number == 1000000)
  return result.split(" ").delete_if { |word| word == "zero"}.join(" ") if result.include?("zero") && number > 0 
  result
end

def in_words(number)
  #base case
  return NUMBER_DICTIONARY[number] if NUMBER_DICTIONARY.include?(number)
  #recursion
  return in_words(number / 1000000) + " " + in_words(1000000) + " " + in_words(number % 1000000) if number > 1000000
  return in_words(number / 1000) + " " + in_words(1000) + " " + in_words(number % 1000) if number > 1000
  return in_words(number / 100) + " " + in_words(100) + " " + in_words(number % 100) if number > 100
  return in_words((number / 10) * 10) + " " + in_words(number % 10) if number > 20 

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix your recursive algorithm using a default parameter:

```
SCALES = [1000000, 1000, 100]

def in_words(number, start = true)

  return 'negative ' + in_words(-number) if number < 0

  # One of the scales in spoken English
  return 'one ' + in_words(number, false) if SCALES.include?(number) and start

  #base case
  return NUMBER_DICTIONARY[number] if NUMBER_DICTIONARY.include?(number)

  SCALES.each do |n|
    if number > n
      result = []
      result << in_words(number/n)
      result << in_words(n, false)
      result << in_words(number % n, false) unless number % n == 0
      return result.join(' ')
    end
  end

  # This can only ever be reached when 100 > number > 20
  return in_words((number / 10) * 10) + " " + in_words(number % 10)
end
```

`start` is true by default and signals this is potentially the start of a [scale in spoken English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales). If the number is at the start of the scale, it might get prefixed with 'one'. Identifying those scales also allowed me to generalize some repeated code. When looking up a name for a number after the start of the scale, I set `start` to false.

Getting rid of the final 'zero' is even easier. If the number in the one's place is zero, we don't say it in English.

Concatenating strings occasionally resulted in extra spaces between words in my testing, so I changed to building up arrays and joining them.

Finally, I added support for negative numbers.

Please note: I tested this on a bunch of edge cases that I though of, but there still might be errors lurking.